# Как отобразить форму в контроле?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Есть `groupBox` в который я хочу добавить форму.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  Form2 frm = new Form2();
  groupBox.Controls.Add(frm);
 }
```

Выводит ошибку. Есть ли обходной метод отобразить форму в контроле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Было изначально

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
```

после того как вместо `Form` добавил `UserControl` все заработало

```
 public partial class Form2 : UserControl
```